# What priority has an enqueued child job in Hangfire when using ContinueWith?

Tags: c#, .net, background-process, hangfire

My application is using Hangfire for background job processing.
I create the background jobs as follows:

```
var parentJobId = _backgroundJobClient.Enqueue<IMyService>(x => x.ParentMethod(id));
_backgroundJobClient.ContinueWith<IMyService>(parentJobId, x => x.ChildMethod(id));

_backgroundJobClient.Enqueue<IMyService>(x => x.OtherMethod1(id));
_backgroundJobClient.Enqueue<IMyService>(x => x.OtherMethod2(id));
```

Those methods are defined in the service as follows:

```
public interface IMyService
{
    [Queue(HangfireQueuePriority.Default)]
    void ParentMethod(int id);

    [Queue(HangfireQueuePriority.Default)]
    void ChildMethod(int id);       

    [Queue(HangfireQueuePriority.Default)]
    void OtherMethod1(int id);  

    [Queue(HangfireQueuePriority.Critical)]
    void OtherMethod2(int id);      
}
```

I'd like the ChildMethod to be running as soon as the parent job has finished.
My understanding of ContinueWith is that the child job runs after the parent job, but it is not specified in the Hangfire documentation how soon the child task will run.

My question is what is the "priority" of the child task over other tasks in a queue?
Is there a chance that any task defined in the queue will run between the ParentMethod and the ChildMethod? e.g. OtherMethod1 or OtherMethod2

Answer (score 0):

> My question is what is the "priority" of the child task over other
>   tasks in a queue?

[All jobs in critical queues will be fetched first before default queues](http://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/background-processing/configuring-queues.html) regardless of level of concurrency.

> Is there a chance that any task defined in the queue will run between
>   the ParentMethod and the ChildMethod? e.g. OtherMethod1 or
>   OtherMethod2

Technically speaking based on my first answer to your first queues all jobs in critical queue will be fetched first and that will include your `OtherMethod2`. Now all remaining jobs are in `Defaults Queue` and by default Hangfire is setup to execute jobs in Concurrently base on available number of [Worker](http://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/background-processing/configuring-degree-of-parallelism.html). Meaning there is a chance that `OtherMethod1` can run between `ParentMethod` and `ChildMethod` because they all under `Default Queues`.

Comment: That makes sense. However, there is one thing not clear to me. 
What is it going to happen when a Critical task (OtherMethod2) is added to the queue right after the ParentMethod has started being processed (before ChildMethod is processed)? 
Which task will be processed first: the Crital task (OtherMethod2) or the ChildMethod task?

Answer (score 0):

For this issue, I use 2 hangfire servers. 
The first is using queues like this "Continue,Default"
The second like this "Default,Continue"

your continue with has to be in the Continue queue.

So with this, when a task come in Continue queue, if the first is occupied, the second server take it, even if it's occupied with default job.

I use this because when i have a batch with thousands of enqueue and thousands of continuewith, i want the 2 queues to run in parallel.